# How to write a percolator query to nest program

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a percolator query in elastic search as below.

```
put /skill-index

PUT /skill-index/skill-type/_mapping
{
    "properties" : {
        "message" : {
            "type": "string"
        }

    }

}

PUT /skill-index/.percolator/101
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "crossstitch"
        }
    }

}

PUT /skill-index/.percolator/102
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "chainstitch"
        }
    }

}

PUT /skill-index/.percolator/103
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "stemstitch"
        }
    }

}

PUT /skill-index/.percolator/104
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "longandshort"
        }
    }

}



GET /skill-index/skill-type/_percolate  
{
    "doc" : {
        "message" : "Know chainstitch and stemstitch"
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to have the GET query in my NEST program.
eg. I have an entity called as skillentity. And I will be passing a variable string, such as "Know chainstitch and stemstitch".

I want to retrieve the value as 102,103

So I should be framing something like
declare a list
List skillsList= new List

After that I want to a lambda expression query, something like.

var skillsList = client.Percolate(...... pass the variable and get the result..)

Could you please help me in framing the query in NEST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example will explain how to deal with percolators in NEST

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var indexName = "indexname";

        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
            .SetDefaultIndex(indexName)
            .EnableTrace();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var indicesResponse = client.DeleteIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));

        client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).AddMapping<Document>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));

        var percolate = client.RegisterPercolator<Document>("p1",
            descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Name).Query("test"))));

        var percolate2 = client.RegisterPercolator<Document>("p2",
            descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(f => f.Name).Query("something"))));

        var percolateResponse =
            client.Percolate<Document>(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).Document(new Document {Name = "this is a test"}));

        //Matches contain percolator p1 
        var percolatorIds = percolateResponse.Matches.Select(x => x.Id);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```